# Compare two dataframes and remove rows from a df based on a matching column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas df which look like this:

```
df1:

pid Name score age
100  Ram     3  36
101 Tony     2  40
101 Jack     4  56
200 Jill     6  30

df2
pid Name score age
100  Ram     3  36
101 Tony     2  40
101 John     4  51
101 Jack     9  32
200 Jill     6  30
```

Both df's are indexed with 'pid'. I would like to compare df1 & df2 based on the column 'score'. i.e, I need to keep only those rows in df2 that are matching with df1 on index and value of score.

My expected result should be

```
new df2:
pid Name index age
100  Ram     3  36
101 Tony     2  40
101 John     4  51
200 Jill     6  30
```

Any help on this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by columns `pid` and `score`, but first create columns from index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), last create `pid` index again and for same columns of new `DataFrame` add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `df2.columns`:

```
df = (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), 
               df2.reset_index(), on=['score', 'pid'], how='left', suffixes=['_',''])
        .set_index('pid')
        .reindex(columns=df2.columns))

print (df)
     Name  score  age
pid                  
100   Ram      3   36
101  Tony      2   40
101  John      4   51
200  Jill      6   30
```

Inputs:

```
print (df1)
     Name  score  age
pid                  
100   Ram      3   36
101  Tony      2   40
101  Jack      4   56
200  Jill      6   30

print (df2)
     Name  score  age
pid                  
100   Ram      3   36
101  Tony      2   40
101  John      4   51
101  Jack      9   32
200  Jill      6   30
```